# Access WCF Authentication information from the Service Side

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I use this code to authenticate to my WCF Service:

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

Is there any way to access this information from within a method of my WCF Service code? (I'm not interested in the password used, more the username for audit purposes.)

I'm trying to determine the identity of the user calling the method without changing the method signiture to include another parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking into the [ServiceSecurityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext(VS.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the user name of the caller like this:

```
ServiceSecurityContext ssc = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;

if (!ssc.IsAnonymous && ssc.PrimaryIdentity != null)
{
    string userName = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
}
```

The `PrimaryIdentity` will contain a "normal" IIdentity and has all the fields (like IsAuthenticated etc.) that the identity object class carries.

Marc